# How can I allow nulls to be accepted by my WebAPI model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Model Class:

```
public class UserData
{
    public IList<bool> Checked { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Matches { get; set; }
    public int TestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The data coming from my client looks like this:

```
{"Checked":[true,true,false,false,false,false],"Matches":null,"TestQuestionId":480,"Text":null}
```

Do I need to modify my model class if it is possible that some of the 
data may not be present and if so then how could I modify the IList ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: which fields do you wish to be null?

Comment: Actually any field except testQuestionId could be null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the field you are trying to deserialize is a [Value Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), and your JSON says its `null`, then you need to change it to a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) field.

If the value being transferred as null is a [Reference Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx), there isn't a need to change anything, as a Reference Type can be null. When deserializing the JSON, the value will remain null.

For example, lets say `TestQuestionId` was null in your JSON:

```
{
   "Checked": [true,true,false,false,false,false],
   "Matches": null,
   "TestQuestionId": null,
   "Text":null
}
```

If you wanted to deserialize that JSON properly, you would have to declare `TestQuestionId` as a `Nullable<int>`, like this:

```
public class UserData
{
    public IList<bool> Checked { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Matches { get; set; }
    public int? TestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

To make it simple and clear: Value Types (int, uint, double, sbyte, etc) cannot be assigned a null value, that is why `Nullable<T>` (A.K.A Nullable Types) were invented. Reference Types (string, custom classes) may be assigned a null value.

Comment: So there's no null equivalent for IList<Matches> as for a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "null equivalent"? IList<Matches> may be null.

Comment: @SamanthaJ `IList` are nullable types so there is no need for explicit nullable declarations, but `int` is not, it is a value type by default, that is why it required explicit nullable declarations.

Comment: @SamanthaJ only C# Value Types have to be explicitly marked nullable. Any other type can be null without being explicitly marked, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Excerpt: Unlike reference types, a value type cannot contain the null value. However, the nullable types feature does allow for value types to be assigned to null.