# How to handle datatypes posted from Angular to WebAPI?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am facing this problem where my API resource (View Model) has datatypes like `int` or `long`. In my Angular App I am using `reactive forms` and after it's initialization, all controls take `null` value.

i.e.

```
this.patientRestrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      patientFileId: new FormControl(null),.......
```

and the JSON output is

```
{ "patientFileId": null}
```

in my API controller this `null` is recognized as a `string` and hence the model fails to pass the validation check,

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return StatusCode (400, ModelState);
};
```

This is a snapshot of the resource model,

```
public class SavePatientsRegistryResource {
        [Display (Name = "Patient File Id")]
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
......
}
```

One more **problem** here is that the `ModelState` error is always empty for `datatypes` other than `string`.

What am I missing here?,

shall I use `string` `datatype` for all my properties in my resource model and `parse` downstream prior to saving data?

Thank you.

Comment: If null is expected why not use nullable types ? Like public long? PatientFileId {get; set;}

Comment: Because its not always expected `null`, if the user does not enter a value, `formControl` default value will remain `null`.

Comment: set 0 instead of setting it null for default value

Comment: 0 is a value, some of those fields might take it as a valid value even if the user forgot to fill it up

Comment: @JSON - It is the purpose of nullable types, if long can have null along with any other expected value you can use it see more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Comment: I understand but what is happening here is that the posted null is recognized as a string, basically a datatype conflict (long and string)

Comment: One issue not mentioned is that you are using `long`. Just as an FYI, JS has 64-bit signed floating point numbers only. This allows you to store 53-bit signed integers, but `long` is 64-bit signed integers in C#. If you will spill over that, you'll need to do special processing.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWStrimpel, I am facing the same issue with int as well

Comment: This is what I am talking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865790/how-can-i-allow-nulls-to-be-accepted-by-my-webapi-model , should work for you.

Comment: @RaviA., basically I have to make all my prop. Nullable?

Comment: Not all the ones you expecting possibly be null.

Comment: The problem angular gives all datatype a null value at initialization and they remain if the user does not change them

Comment: According to post that you linked above, its still possible to change all prop to sting and parse them to their datatypes that matches their model counterparts. right?

Comment: Did you try changing all the properties to nullable, string types are by default so except string you can change rest. Changing all types to string and then parsing will become a overhead but that will work too, although not recommended. What is the issue with nullable types ? Nullable type has properties like hasvalue etc so you should be able to identify if null is passed or an actual value on your API so should solve your issue.

Comment: Agreed, conversion resource prop to string and parse downstream will add just a boilerplate and its a headache. can you please post your comment as an answer. You just answered my question. Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170444/discussion-between-json-and-ravi-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nullable types i.e. change your properties as below

```
public long? PatientFileId {get; set;}
```

References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

[How can I allow nulls to be accepted by my WebAPI model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865790/how-can-i-allow-nulls-to-be-accepted-by-my-webapi-model)

Further Nullable type has properties like hasvalue etc so you should be able to identify if null is passed or an actual value on your API so should solve your issue.

Hope this helps.